# How does one create a loop with indefinite nested loops?

Tags: ruby, loops

say you have a list [ 1 , 2 ,3 ...... n]
if you needed to compare two elements so you would write something like

```
list = (0..9999).to_a

idx = 0

while idx < list.length
  idx2 = idx
  while idx2 < list.length
    puts list[idx] + list[idx2] if (list[idx] + list[idx2]).odd?
    idx2 += 1
  end
  idx += 1
end
```

But what if the number of comparisons is not constant and increases?
This code hard codes the comparison by having one loop inside another, but if you needed to compare 4 or more elements how does one write a loop or something that achieves this if you don't know the maximum number of comparisons?

Answer (score 2):

We have a helpful method in ruby to do this, and that is [Array#combination](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
def find_odd_sums(list, num_per_group)
  list.combination(num_per_group).to_a.map(&:sum).select(&:odd?)
end
```

You can re-implement `combination`, if you choose to. There are many versions of this function available at [Algorithm to return all combinations of k elements from n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n)

Comment: You can remove the `Enumerator#to_a` after `Array#combination`. I can't remove it because it's less than 6 chars.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not clear. Firstly, the title, which is vague, asks how a particular approach to an unstated problem can be implemented. What you need, at the beginning, is a statement in words of the problem.

I will make a guess as to what that statement might be and then propose a solution.

Given

- an array `arr`;
- a positive integer `n`, `1 <= n <= arr.size`; and
- a method `m` having `n` arguments that are distinct elements of `arr` that returns `true` or `false`,

what combinations of `n` elements of `arr` cause `m` to return `true`?

We can use the following method combined with a definition of the method `m`.

```
def combos(arr, n, m)
  arr.combination(n).select { |x| public_send(m, *x) }
end
```

The key, of course, is the method [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-combination). See also the docs for the methods [Enumerable#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) and [Object#public_send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Object.html#method-i-public_send).

Here is its use with the example given in the question.

```
def m(*x)
  x.sum.odd?
end

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

combos(arr, 2, :m)
  #=> [[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 6], [2, 3], [2, 5], [3, 4], [3, 6], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
combos(arr, 3, :m)
  #=> [[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 6],
  #    [2, 4, 5], [2, 5, 6], [3, 4, 6], [4, 5, 6]]
combos(arr, 4, :m)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 6], [2, 4, 5, 6]]
```

See the doc for [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) (which made it's debut in Ruby v2.4.

Here's a second example: given an array of letters, which combinations of five letters have two vowels?

```
VOWEL_COUNTER = %w| a e i o u |.product([1]).to_h.tap { |h| h.default=0 }
  #=> {"a"=>1, "e"=>1, "i"=>1, "o"=>1, "u"=>1}
VOWEL_COUNTER['a']
  #=> 1
```

By setting the hash's default value to zero, `VOWEL_COUNTER[k]` will return zero if it does not have a key `k`. For example,

```
VOWEL_COUNTER['r']
  #=> 0

def m(*x)
  x.sum { |c| VOWEL_COUNTER[c] } == 2
end

arr = %w| a r t u e v s |    
combos(arr, 5, :m)
  #=> [["a", "r", "t", "u", "v"], ["a", "r", "t", "u", "s"],
  #    ["a", "r", "t", "e", "v"], ["a", "r", "t", "e", "s"],
  #    ["a", "r", "u", "v", "s"], ["a", "r", "e", "v", "s"],
  #    ["a", "t", "u", "v", "s"], ["a", "t", "e", "v", "s"],
  #    ["r", "t", "u", "e", "v"], ["r", "t", "u", "e", "s"],
  #    ["r", "u", "e", "v", "s"], ["t", "u", "e", "v", "s"]]
```

Note that `VOWEL_COUNTER` is constructed as follows.

```
a = %w| a e i o u |
  #=> ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
b = a.product([1])
  #=> [["a", 1], ["e", 1], ["i", 1], ["o", 1], ["u", 1]]
c = b.to_h
  #=> {"a"=>1, "e"=>1, "i"=>1, "o"=>1, "u"=>1}
```

With this hash,

```
c['r']
  #=> nil
```

so we need to set the default value to zero.

```
VOWEL_COUNTER = c.tap { |h| h.default=0 }
  #=> {"a"=>1, "e"=>1, "i"=>1, "o"=>1, "u"=>1}
c['r']
  #=> 0
```

Alternatively, we could have omitted the last step (setting the hash's default to zero), and written

```
x.sum { |c| VOWEL_COUNTER[c].to_i } == 2
```

because [NilClass#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/NilClass.html#method-i-to_i) converts `nil` to zero.

See also the docs for the methods #select, #public_send

Answer (score 0):

I feel like everyone is making this more complicated than it is. You sure got pointed to the right direction ([`Array#combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-combination), [`Array#repeated_combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-repeated_combination), [`Array#permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-permutation), [`Array#repeated_permutation`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation)). To accomplish the exact thing you are doing, you can simply do:

```
list.repeated_combination(2) { |c| puts c.sum if c.sum.odd? }
```

*Check the links above to see the difference between them.*

If you want to create a helper method you can, but in my opinion it's not really needed in this case. Replace `2` with the number you are looking for and you got your answer.